# How to match a 10 digit phone number which may or maynot be have a 2 or 3 digit country code.The country code is not to be matched

Tags: regex

Example string

```
fgcfghhfghfgch1234567890fghfghfgh fhghghfgh+916546546165fghfghfghfgh fhfghfghfghfgh+915869327425ghfghfghfgh
```

I want to match

```
1234567890
6546546165
5869327425
```

In essence i would like to do something like this `(?<=\+\d{2})?\d{10}`.
Match 10 digits `\d{10}` which may follow `?` a country code in format: `\+\d{2}`.
What would be a correct regular expression to do this?

Also,
What to do if the country code could possibly be even 3 digit long.
e.g.

```
+917458963214
+0047854123698
```

match `7854123698` and `7458963214`.

Comment: You should use a captuirng group here, `(?:\+\d{2,3})?(\d{10})`. Or, use `\K`,  `(?:\+\d{2,3})?\K\d{10}`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OnDxUA/1). Add `(?!\d)` at the end and replace `(?:\+\d{2,3})?` with `(?:\+\d{2,3}|(?<!\d))` to ensure you fail the match if there are more than 10 digits.

Comment: This Java example will handle any phone number, all you need to do is to add the variations want to match. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex/63771966#63771966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected matches all appear to be immediately followed with a char other than a digit.

I suggest making the pattern inside the positive lookbehind optional and adding `(?!\d)` lookahead at the end to fail the match (and thus triggering backtracking in the lookbehind)  if the ten digits are immediately followed with a digit:

```
(?<=(?:\+\d{2,3})?)\d{10}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OnDxUA/2). **Details**:

- `(?<=(?:\+\d{2,3})?)` - a positive lookbehind that requires `+` and two or three digits or an empty string immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{10}` - ten digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately on the right.

**However**, as in 99% you can access *captured* substrings, you should just utilize a capturing group:

```
(?:\+\d{2,3})?(\d{10})
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OnDxUA/3). Your values are in Group 1.